# R: Accessing a Data Frame using a List

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to coding so bear with me.  I'm working on an R assignment that requires me to create a function to pick columns from existing data frames using a mixed character list and then create a new data frame from those picked columns.

I realize this is probably trivial using a bunch of add-ons, but I'm trying to understand what I'm missing with the interaction between data frames and lists.

Right now, I've been testing stuff in my console to better understand what's going on with accessing dataframes.

I understand that I want to get some sort of accessor for my using MyDataFrame[___], but it seems that using a list is incorrect in this situation, since I'm getting an error that says it's an unsupported index type: list.

Am I incorrectly accessing the individual components of the list when I apply them to the data frame accessor?

Edit:

sorry for the lack of details.
I am using ggplot2's mpg data frame to test things out, so this is what I've been plugging into the console:

mylist<-list(1,2,"drv") #This works just fine

mpg[mylist] #This doesn't work at all, I get Error: Unsupported Index Type.

Basically, I'm trying to access the three columns from the data.frame using the List as my list of accessor.

---

Just thought I'd share my solution since I completed this and I heard people like things that are complete:

```
selectCols<-function(data, ...){
#need to generate a list from the ... argument
  arguments<-list(...)   #Create a New Data Frame using the list created above
  for (i in 1:length(arguments)){
    if(i==1){
      mydataframe<-cbind(data[arguments[[i]]])}
    else{ 
      mydataframe<-cbind(mydataframe,data[arguments[[i]]])
    }
  }
  print(mydataframe)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the code you have worked on so far. It's always much better to be as specific and descriptive as you can when asking questions. If we know what code you've used it will be easier for us to help you! You should also look into how to make a [reprex (reproducible example)](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html) so in the future your questions will more robust.

Comment: Please update your question to include a *specific* problem statement, and desired result. As it is currently written your question lacks the specifics we need to answer it well.

Comment: Oh, sure.  Sorry.  I am using ggplot2's mpg data frame to test things out, so this is what I've been plugging into the console:

mylist<-list(1,2,"drv") #This works just fine


mpg[mylist] #This doesn't work at all, I get Error: Unsupported Index Type.

Basically, I'm trying to access the three columns from the data.frame using the List as my list of accessor.

Comment: Do please add this important information *in your question*, not burying it down here in comments.

Comment: yes, class list, not just vectors.

Comment: Hmm, interesting problem. Is your goal to (a) create/overwrite existing methods so that `mpg[mylist]` does work, or (b) create a new function like `foo(mpg, mylist)` that works? (a) is quite a bit more challenging than (b).

Comment: Definitely (b).  I'm a bit confused about the inner workings of this, so I'm just testing something simple right now, and I'm trying to figure out how dataframe accessing interacts with lists.  I think once I get that, I can write the function myself.

Comment: Data frame accessing *doesn't* work with lists, it works with vectors. `mpg[c(1, 2)]` works, and `mpg[c("drv", "cty")]` works. I think your challenge is to write a function that converts your `list` problem into already solved `vector` problems (and combines the results appropriately). (If lists already worked, there wouldn't be anything for you to do...)

Comment: I don't really know how much help you want. As a first step, I'd split the list into two vectors - one with the integers, one with the characters. `?Filter` may be a good place to start, followed by `unlist`...

Comment: This is perfect.  It at least lets me test out a bunch of new things.  I've got time before this is due anyway, so I just want to make sure I understand this stuff for when I have to do the crazy pen and paper exams.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access a data frame, then using a vector would be easier than using a list. E.g.

```
columns_to_access <- c("year", "drv")
mpg[columns_to_access]
```

But you are also mixing columns names and column indices, so

```
mpg[c("year", "drv")]
```

will work, as will

```
mpg[1:2]
```

<strike>but not a mixture.</strike>

Edit: It is possible to use a mixture if you use the package "dplyr", as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223807/10923234)

Comment: Yeah, I tested that, but I am supposed to use a list.  When I access a data frame, I can use MyDataFrame[index] and My DataFrame['heading'], so it seems like I'm missing something in how to use lists properly.

Thank you though!

Comment: Is there are reason that you need to use a list here? If you already have one stored you could use `unlist` to flatten it to a vector when passing it to the dataframe?

Comment: It's part of the assignment, haha.  No other good reason.  I asked for specifics, and my eventual function is supposed to be able to handle mixed inputs.  The unlist function might be really good.  I didn't realize that was a function.

Thanks!