# Use data frame that should return both numeric and character columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a built in data set in R called `"mpg"`. When I type

```
df(,c[1,2,"year"])
```

the result( it should print respective tables) should be

```
**manufactures**  **model**  **year**
1) audi        a4.    1999
2) audi.       a4.    1999
    .           .      .
    .           .      .
    .           .      .
224)
```

Comment: You can have only either one of those.  If you have column index for majority of columns and a column names, convert it to a single one with `match` i.e. `df[c(1:2, match("year", names(df)))]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mix the ways with which you subset the columns of a dataframe, you can use dplyr.

#### Sample dataset:

```
mtcars

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% select(1, 2, "drat")
```

#### Output

```
                     mpg cyl drat
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 3.90
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 3.90
Datsun 710          22.8   4 3.85
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 3.08
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 3.15
```

Answer (score 0):

`mpg[,c(1,2,4)]`

Is what you're looking for.

or

`mpg[, c("manufacturer", "model", "year")]`

Comment: Hey thanks, any idea how should I pass this data frame in a function that returns results in data.frame?

Comment: Not quite sure exactly what you mean. Do you have an ideal or pseudocode of the function and output.

Comment: function(data, col 1, col 2 , "col3(string)").  In this data should be  data.frame to subset column name and other arguments are column numbers and column name.